# Looking for jQuery Content Slider Recommendation

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a jQuery content slider plugin that can support the following:

- Let's me slide between divs (all my slides are in different divs)
- Let's me control, based on in-slide logic, what the next slide should be
- Let's me add my own back/forth buttons but gives me control over which slide to go back/forward to

Basically, I'm building a little wizard where each slide will ask a few questions and depending on the users' answers, that determines what the next slide will be.

Have any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give [this](http://bxslider.com/) a try, I've used it on two of my sites and it works wonderfully.